# Bash list files with range

Tags: bash, ls

My script has to list all files between a given range of date within a file name (ex: 20130133.212001.log). The start date and end date will be given by user. I now have start_year, end_year, start_month, end_month....so on till end_second. My plan was to use ls syntax:

```
ls *{start_year..end_year}{start_month..end_month}{.....}.log
```

But the problem is if month or date has 01 bash is taking it as 1. Indeed my bash version is older than 4. I can't considering updating the bash version.
Any other method that I use to list files in such range.

[EDIT]

```
$> cat tmp.sh
#! /bin/bash

start_year=2013
end_year=2013
start_month=01
end_month=01
start_date=01
end_date=12

start_month=$(printf %02d $start_month)
end_month=$(printf %02d $end_month)

start_date=$(printf %02d $start_date)
end_date=$(printf %02d $end_date)
ls {$start_year..$end_year}{$start_month..$end_month}{$start_date..$end_date}.log
$>
```

but output is:

```
$>./tmp.sh
ls: {2013..2013}{01..01}{01..12}.log: No such file or directory
```

while the current dir contains:

```
$> ls
20130101.log  20130103.log  20130105.log  20130107.log  20130109.log  20130111.log  20130201.log  abcd.log
20130102.log  20130104.log  20130106.log  20130108.log  20130110.log  20130112.log  2013.log      tmp.sh
$>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about like this:

```
start=$start_year$(printf %02d $start_month)
end=$end_year$(printf %02d $end_month)
ls *.log | sed -ne "/$start/,/$end/p"
```

Comment: Janos, all of year, month and date may have range. It may even contain hr, min and sec. So I tried this:`$ cat tmp.sh [ASM-SW1-BT02:/home/lsm/gjois/tmp] cat tmp.sh 
#! /bin/bash

start_year=2013
end_year=2013
start_month=01
end_month=01
start_date=01
end_date=12

start_month=$(printf %02d $start_month)
end_month=$(printf %02d $end_month)

start_date=$(printf %02d $start_date)
end_date=$(printf %02d $end_date)

ls {$start_year..$end_year}{$start_month..$end_month}{$start_date..$end_date}.log
[ASM-SW1-BT02:/home/lsm/gjois/tmp]`

Comment: but output is: `[ASM-SW1-BT02:/home/lsm/gjois/tmp] ./tmp.sh 
ls: {2013..2013}{01..01}{01..12}.log: No such file or directory` while the current dir contains:`[ASM-SW1-BT02:/home/lsm/gjois/tmp] ls
20130101.log  20130103.log  20130105.log  20130107.log  20130109.log  20130111.log  20130201.log  abcd.log
20130102.log  20130104.log  20130106.log  20130108.log  20130110.log  20130112.log  2013.log      tmp.sh
[ASM-SW1-BT02:/home/lsm/gjois/tmp] `

Comment: Too hard to read, because of the broken formatting. Please paste with the correct formatting into your question.

Comment: @user2763554 well, I see you're not using my proposed solution, filtering the output of `ls` with `sed`. I recommend you try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize `printf` facility in that case.

Consider this script:

```
for i in {1..2}; do for j in {01..12}; do printf "%02d%02d\n" $i $j; done; done
```

**UPDATE: For using variable:

```
start=1
end=2
for ((i=start; i<=end; i++)); do
   for ((j=1; j<=12; j++)); do printf "%02d%02d\n" $i $j; done
done

0101
0102
0103
0104
0105
0106
0107
0108
0109
0110
0111
0112
0201
0202
0203
0204
0205
0206
0207
0208
0209
0210
0211
0212
```

Comment: anubhava...this method doesnt seems to take range as subsitiuted variables: `$> start=1
$> end=2
$> for i in {$start..$end}; do for j in {01..12}; do printf "%02d%02d\n" $i $j; done; done
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0001
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0002
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0003
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0004
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0005
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0006
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0007
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0008
-bash: printf: {1..2}: invalid number
0009 <<snipped>>
$> `

Comment: No it doesn't take variables. If you want variable values to be passed in the I need to edit my code.

Comment: ok. but this doesn't seems to work if user hasn't provided hr, min and sec. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by `user hasn't provided hr, min and sec`? In your script I don't see any min and sec variables.

Comment: That was a stripped version of my actual script. User may give date as YYYYDDMM.hhmmss or YYYYDDMM or even YYYY_DD_MM. I have arrived untill splitting it to start_year, end_year... so on