# How to search range of files using dates in php?

Tags: php, file, search, range, glob

I am trying to make a php file searching tool that uses range of dates obtained from a form. 
I have directories that have the following patter. There are thousands of files but this is just an example.

daily folder

```
 chl-2009-05-08-121000.L2_LAC.x.png
 chl-2009-05-09-111500.L2_LAC.x.png
 chl-2009-05-09-112000.L2_LAC.x.png etc
```

weekly folder

```
lst-2014-W36.png
lst-2014-W37.png
lst-2014-W39.png etc
```

The form has a parameter field which will get chl, lst, and others. The other fields are from the form date, week, etc input fields.

So what I want to achieve is for example, find all files with file names ranging from `2002-04-14` and `2003-05-25`. I have a variable that provides the date.

What I have done till now only list files that exactly match the provided values with wildcard but I couldn't get all files within date ranges. I have attempted for the daily folder.

```
$a = glob($datadir."{". $_GET['parameter'] .'-'.  $_GET["date"]. "*,". $_GET['parameter'] .'-'.  $_GET["date2"]. "*}" , GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($a as $image) 
    {
       echo "<a href='".$image."'>" . basename($image) . "</a><br />";  
    }
```

The reason I used wildcards here is to avoid checking values like these 112000.L2_LAC.x.png.

Thank you!

Comment: i checked twice,  i don't actully see a question

Comment: `I couldn't get range of files` ~ `How can I get the range of files?`

Comment: build your glob string separately, e.g. `$g = "...."; echo $g; glob($g);` so you can inspect it. don't just assume it's being constructed properly.

Comment: With your current scheme you need to glob all files that have something in common and then loop through them and check if the date is `>` or `<`.

Comment: Thank you Dagon and showdev for the advice. I have edited to make it more clear.

Comment: @Marc B and AbraCadaver, the problem is, how could I get range of available files in between two dates?

Comment: `new DirectoryIterator(".")` The purpose of interpreted languages is to speed up development time. You don't need to worry about the internals.

Comment: The problem is not listing directory but find only files within the range of minimum and maximum value. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you don't use PHP's directory listing code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591789/bash-list-files-with-range

Comment: Oh how can I integrate bash in a php website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick would be converting your filenames and $_POST fields to actual dates and then do comparisons. It's too problematic to treat them as numbers or strings & regular expressions.

This code takes care of the `chl` case and `lst` case. You can use the same technique to address others. Bear in mind that `$user_start_date` and `$user_end_date` are PHP dates. Not strings.

At the bottom I hard-coded some start and end dates. Obviously, you would use your $_GET['date'] and $_GET['date2'] values instead. [The PHP docs for DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) contain info on how to convert variously formatted strings into dates.

```
function filesInRange($datadir, $parameter, $user_start_date, $user_end_date) {

    $all_files  = array();
    $good_files = array();

    //  first create an array of all the filenames, to keep I/O to a minimum
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($datadir) as $fileInfo) {
        if ( $fileInfo->isFile() ) {
            $all_files[] = $fileInfo->getFileName();
        }
    }

    switch ($parameter) {

        case 'chl':
        foreach ($all_files as $filename) {
            //  we only operate on filenames that start with "chl". we skip others
            if ( strpos($filename, $parameter) === 0 ) {
                $pattern = '/(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})-(?<hour>\d{2})(?<minute>\d{2})(?<second>\d{2})/';
                preg_match($pattern, $filename, $matches);
                $filedate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-j-His',$matches[0]);
                //  check range
                if ($filedate >= $user_start_date && $filedate <= $user_end_date) {
                    $good_files[ $filedate->getTimestamp() ] = $filename;
                }
            }
        }
        break;

        case 'lst':
        foreach ($all_files as $filename) {
            if ( strpos($filename, $parameter) === 0 ) {
                $pattern = '/(?<year>\d{4})-W(?<week>\d{1,2})/';
                preg_match($pattern, $filename, $matches);
                //  start on Jan 1 and keep adding days until we reach our desired week
                $file_start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s',$matches['year'].'-01-01 00:00:00');
                while ( $file_start_date->format('W') < $matches['week'] ) {
                    $file_start_date->modify('+1 day');
                }
                //  add one week to get the end date
                //  the start day starts on the very first second of the day (00:00:00)
                //  the end date ends on the last second (23:59:59)
                $file_end_date = clone $file_start_date;
                $file_end_date->modify('+8 day');
                $file_end_date->modify('-1 second');

                //  check range
                if ($file_start_date >= $user_start_date && $file_end_date <= $user_end_date) {
                    $good_files[ $file_start_date->getTimestamp() ] = $filename;
                }
            }
        }
        break;

        case 'some_other_format':
        //  handle other formats
        break;

    }
    return $good_files;
}

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-j-His','2013-08-01-121000');
$end   = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-j-His','2015-09-15-121000');

$result1 = filesInRange($datadir, 'lst', $start, $end );

var_dump($result1);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sure now, this is the right direction. The files within that range comes but I am getting two errors. I am getting errors Notice:Undefined property: DirectoryIterator::$isDot .. and Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in .. How could apply the same concept for weekly? Because it has W in the name. Also I have another one which is Year - first letter of each months. for instance. The form value is 2012-JFM.tif = 2012-JanuaryFebruaryMarch

Comment: The "undefined property" error is because there is a syntax error in my code. I will update my answer to include the fix, and fill in the `lst` case. By examining those two cases, and reading the documentation for DateTime::createFromFormat(), you should be able to figure out how to fill in the `2012-JFM` case.

Comment: I will wait for your fix on the undefinded notice. I have managed to figure out to display lst-2014-W36.png and yyyy-mm case. The 2012-JFM case is a bit tricky. That is what I am going to study on. I can start with 'JFM'='JanuaryFebruaryMarch' or 'JFM'='JanFebMar'. I can even rename the files to JaanFebMar but I couldn't get the idea of sorting them and get range like date, month or week.

Comment: The JFM format works after changing it to YYYY-Jan-Feb-Mar format! Then I used 'substr' to have YYYY-Jan so that it is easier to get it work. Then I used this  $pattern = '/(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\w{3})/'; I have one question. How could I sort $good_files having data like this tsm-2013-Jan-Feb-Mar.png

Comment: great question! I think the most performant way would be to create a sparse array whose keys are timestamps per http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php. I've included that in my updated code.

Comment: btw, the issue with `$fileInfo->isDot` was that it was supposed to be `$fileInfo->isDot()`. In other words, it's a method, and not a property. http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdot.php

Comment: Yes, true. Thanks mate. Is there a better place to sort files with months? the php.net url is not that informative.

Comment: a user defined sorting function could be your saviour here. We are taking the same approach: convert to dates and then do comparisons. http://3v4l.org/WSaS3 & http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Great! I will read further on that! I couldn't do away with undefined offset error for $matches[0]. How could I solve it?

Comment: that occurs when the regular expression (`$pattern`) does not match the file. `preg_match` returns either an array filled with the regular expression matches, or `false` if there was no match. you could avoid that error if you wrapped your code in `if ($match) { // code goes here }`

Comment: Thank you! The errors are gone now! I will have to now work on sort by month using your advice. If I fail, I will post a question. I will update you here.

Comment: I finally got permission to click the up buttons! Thanks!

Comment: Hello Sean! I discovered a new issue. The week format, YYYY-W22, format, couldn't get the range of files, it displays everything. The problem was there since you gave me the answer but I only found out today. Is there any fix you could do for it? Thanks!

Comment: that is strange. i just tested the code and it works for me. It correctly limits the returned files to the specified range. what version of php are you running? i have 5.5.14. Check to see that `$matches['week']` is what you expect

Comment: Yea, that is strange. I use php 5.5.12. Let me be honest with you. If you remember, you posted a solution for the first time and updated it. So I used the first post and went further with it. So it was working well with all except weekly. So I came and tested your updated code for weekly and still didn't work and didnt work for daily too.I have made minor modifications but it is better if you see both codes. I have uploaded them on drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4XFkaZHDu8BdGVOdUY5YkJvaFk/view?usp=sharing   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4XFkaZHDu8BS3lSMUhBM2E3eVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see two problems: 1) you should be using [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (`===`) rather than loose (`==`) in your `if ( strpos($filename, 'lst') === 0 )` line. 2) you are not passing a valid date string ('2011-W35') to `DateTime::createFromFormat()`, according to the [mask you specified](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) ('Y-m-d G:i:s')

Comment: Ok, I corrected the first one. For the second one, what is the valid date string?

Comment: 'Y-m-d G:i:s' is a mask for a string that looks like 2014-08-31 10:05:59

Comment: then change your date mask. look at the [docs](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for reference

Comment: And I feel the previous code is easier to understand working for other formats. I just need right format for week. Just like 'Y-m-d'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64132/discussion-between-andex-and-sean9999).

Answer (score 1):

Finally range search for all date formats is working.

This code below is drived from sean9999's original post. It works for date (YYYY-MM-DD), month (YYYY-MM) and seasonal = monthly (YYYY-Jan).

```
function filesInRange($datadir, $timeper1, $timeper2, $format, $patternval) {
  $matches=array();
  $good_files = array(); 
  $start = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format,$timeper1);
  $end   = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format,$timeper2);   
  $matches=array(); 

  foreach (new DirectoryIterator($datadir) as $fileInfo) {

    if ( !$fileInfo->isDot() && $fileInfo->isFile() ) {
        //  create a date by parsing the file name
          //$pattern = $patternval ;
          preg_match($patternval, $fileInfo->getFileName(), $matches);
          if ($matches) { 
          $filedate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $matches[0]);
          }//  determine if it's between start and end date
          if ($filedate >= $start && $filedate <= $end) {
              $good_files[] = $datadir.$fileInfo->getFileName();
          }
    }
  }

  asort($good_files); 
  return $good_files; 
}
```

To call the function for daily files.

```
$allfiles=filesInRange( "data/". $_GET["parameter"] . "/daily/", $_GET['date'], $_GET['date2'], 'Y-m-j', '/(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})/');
```

Unfortunately, the [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) doesn't support the week format like `2001W52` or `2001-W52`. Thus, I had to find another way. So with minor modification, I used the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. Here is the code for weekly file search.

```
function filesInRangeweek($datadir, $timeper1, $timeper2, $format, $patternval) {
 $matches=array();
 $good_files = array(); 
 $start = date($format, strtotime($timeper1));
 $end   = date($format, strtotime($timeper2));   
 $matches=array(); 

 foreach (new DirectoryIterator($datadir) as $fileInfo) {

        if ( !$fileInfo->isDot() && $fileInfo->isFile() ) {
            //  create a date by parsing the file name
              //$pattern = $patternval ;
              preg_match($patternval, $fileInfo->getFileName(), $matches);
              if ($matches) { 
                //echo $matches[0];
              $filedate =date($format, strtotime($matches[0]));
              }//  determine if it's between start and end date
              if ($filedate >= $start && $filedate <= $end) {
                  $good_files[] = $datadir.$fileInfo->getFileName();
              }
        }
  }

  asort($good_files); 
  return $good_files; 
}
```

To call the function;

```
$result=filesInRangeweek( "data/lst/weekly/", '2013-W35', '2013-W45',"oW", '/(?<year>\d{4})-W(?<week>\d{2})/');
```